# The input is different in Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

So I made some input blocks for sending a message and it works fine in Chrome and Safari but Firefox shows it with grey borders. There's a problem in IE too because it shows them bigger until you make it active, then it goes back to normal size.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="name">
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Your name" name="name" id="name"/>
</label>
<label for="E-mail">
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Your e-mail" id="email"/>
</label>
<label for="Subject">
<input class="input1" type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" />
</label>
<label for="Message">
<textarea class="input2" name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</label>
<label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    -moz-border-color: #0d1025;
    -moz-border-width:medium;
    border-color: #0d1025;
    border-width:medium;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.input1 {
    width:300px;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
}
.input2 {
    width:650px;
    height:270px;
    margin-left:320px;
    margin-top:-143px;
    border-color: #0d1025;
    border-width:medium;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #0d1025;
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #0d1025;  
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #0d1025;  
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #0d1025;  
   font-style:italic;
   padding-left:15px;
   font-weight:bold;
}
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2core/taQfF/2/

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Thank you! Any ideas about the IE issue? Or does it solve that aswell?

Answer (score 5):

You need to define the `border-style: solid;` as different browsers have different default values.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/taQfF/4/)